# Check all checkboxes with Styled javascript class wont' work

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have a master checkbox when ticked, all checkboxes should be selected. This part works perfect using javascript. If i add a css class to the list of checkboxes using another javascript to give these checkboxes a nice look, the main function of the master checkbox will stop from working properly.

below is the script i use to style the checkbox (checkBoxStyled.js).

```
var checkboxHeight = "25";
var radioHeight = "25";
var selectWidth = "190";

document.write('<style type="text/css">input.styled { display: none; } select.styled {     position: relative; width: ' + selectWidth + 'px; opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0); z-index: 5; } .disabled { opacity: 0.5; filter: alpha(opacity=50); }</style>');

var Custom = {
init: function() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"), span = Array(), textnode, option, active;
    for(a = 0; a < inputs.length; a++) {
        if((inputs[a].type == "checkbox" || inputs[a].type == "radio") && inputs[a].className == "styled") {
            span[a] = document.createElement("span");
            span[a].className = inputs[a].type + "Styled";

            if(inputs[a].checked == true) {
                if(inputs[a].type == "checkbox") {
                    position = "0 -" + (checkboxHeight*2) + "px";
                    span[a].style.backgroundPosition = position;
                } else {
                    position = "0 -" + (radioHeight*2) + "px";
                    span[a].style.backgroundPosition = position;
                }
            }
            inputs[a].parentNode.insertBefore(span[a], inputs[a]);
            inputs[a].onchange = Custom.clear;
            if(!inputs[a].getAttribute("disabled")) {
                span[a].onmousedown = Custom.pushed;
                span[a].onmouseup = Custom.check;
            } else {
                span[a].className = span[a].className += " disabled";
            }
        }
    }
    inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
    for(a = 0; a < inputs.length; a++) {
        if(inputs[a].className == "styled") {
            option = inputs[a].getElementsByTagName("option");
            active = option[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            textnode = document.createTextNode(active);
            for(b = 0; b < option.length; b++) {
                if(option[b].selected == true) {
                    textnode = document.createTextNode(option[b].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                }
            }
            span[a] = document.createElement("span");
            span[a].className = "select";
            span[a].id = "select" + inputs[a].name;
            span[a].appendChild(textnode);
            inputs[a].parentNode.insertBefore(span[a], inputs[a]);
            if(!inputs[a].getAttribute("disabled")) {
                inputs[a].onchange = Custom.choose;
            } else {
                inputs[a].previousSibling.className = inputs[a].previousSibling.className += " disabled";
            }
        }
    }
    document.onmouseup = Custom.clear;
},
pushed: function() {
    element = this.nextSibling;
    if(element.checked == true && element.type == "checkbox") {
        this.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + checkboxHeight*3 + "px";
    } else if(element.checked == true && element.type == "radio") {
        this.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + radioHeight*3 + "px";
    } else if(element.checked != true && element.type == "checkbox") {
        this.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + checkboxHeight + "px";
    } else {
        this.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + radioHeight + "px";
    }
},
check: function() {
    element = this.nextSibling;
    if(element.checked == true && element.type == "checkbox") {
        this.style.backgroundPosition = "0 0";
        element.checked = false;
    } else {
        if(element.type == "checkbox") {
            this.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + checkboxHeight*2 + "px";
        } else {
            this.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + radioHeight*2 + "px";
            group = this.nextSibling.name;
            inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
            for(a = 0; a < inputs.length; a++) {
                if(inputs[a].name == group && inputs[a] != this.nextSibling) {
                    inputs[a].previousSibling.style.backgroundPosition = "0 0";
                }
            }
        }
        element.checked = true;
    }
},
clear: function() {
    inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var b = 0; b < inputs.length; b++) {
        if(inputs[b].type == "checkbox" && inputs[b].checked == true && inputs[b].className == "styled") {
            inputs[b].previousSibling.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + checkboxHeight*2 + "px";
        } else if(inputs[b].type == "checkbox" && inputs[b].className == "styled") {
            inputs[b].previousSibling.style.backgroundPosition = "0 0";
        } else if(inputs[b].type == "radio" && inputs[b].checked == true && inputs[b].className == "styled") {
            inputs[b].previousSibling.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + radioHeight*2 + "px";
        } else if(inputs[b].type == "radio" && inputs[b].className == "styled") {
            inputs[b].previousSibling.style.backgroundPosition = "0 0";
        }
    }
},
choose: function() {
    option = this.getElementsByTagName("option");
    for(d = 0; d < option.length; d++) {
        if(option[d].selected == true) {
            document.getElementById("select" + this.name).childNodes[0].nodeValue = option[d].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        }
    }
}
}
window.onload = Custom.init;
```

Below is the html (index.html). Note that if i remove the class='styled', everything works perfect

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-gb" lang="en-gb" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta name="language" content="en">

<script type="text/javascript" src="checkBoxStyled.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="checkBoxStyled.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="well">
<script type="text/javascript">function check_all(abox) {var table =   document.getElementById('userFlashReports');var cboxes = table.getElementsByTagName('input'); var l = cboxes.length; for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {var n = cboxes[i]; n.checked = abox.checked;}}</script>
<div>
<input name="all" id="title_1" type="checkbox" onclick="check_all(this)" class="styled">
        Toggle All
    </div>
    <div id="userFlashReports">
        <div class="checkboxSpaced">
            <input class="styled" id="UserFlashReportsForm_flashReports_0" value="dmsReport" type="checkbox" name="UserFlashReportsForm[flashReports][]">
            label1
        </div>
        <div class="checkboxSpaced">
            <input class="styled" id="UserFlashReportsForm_flashReports_1" value="gobReport" type="checkbox" name="UserFlashReportsForm[flashReports][]">
            label2
        </div>
        <div class="checkboxSpaced">
            <input class="styled" id="UserFlashReportsForm_flashReports_2" value="marketSegmentReport" checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="UserFlashReportsForm[flashReports][]">
            label3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

the CSS file (checkBoxStyled.css)

```
.checkboxStyled, .radioStyled {
width: 19px;
height: 25px;
padding: 0 5px 0 0;
background: url(checkbox.png) no-repeat;
display: block;
clear: left;
float: left;
}

.selectStyled {
position: absolute;
width: 158px; /* With the padding included, the width is 190 pixels: the actual width of the image. */
height: 21px;
padding: 0 24px 0 8px;
color: #fff;
font: 12px/21px arial,sans-serif;
background: url(select.png) no-repeat;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here is the image [checkbox.png](http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/)

Comment: @Doorknob you stole my edit! (was on the page, hit save, got the message :P same edit too)

Comment: @rlemon I'm a ninja :P

Comment: Any help on this please? can any Javascrpit expert shed some lights on my problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
//Add following styles

.checkboxStyled:checked {
background-position: 0px -50px;
}
.radioStyled :checked {
background-position: 0px -50px;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your quick answer. I did what you are suggesting but it did not do the trick. I think the problem lies somewhere in the javascript code but cannot seem to find it.